# Для чего используется cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), если необходимо возвращать выходное значение хранимой процедуры?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, хранимые-процедуры

```
static int InsertCustomer()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IdentityProcedure", connection) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure };
    SqlParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter());
    parameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; // после выполнения комманды parameter будет содержать возвращаемое значение хранимой процедуры 

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("New customer with CustomerNo {0} was added", parameter.Value);
    return (int)parameter.Value;
}


// код хранимой процедуры 
        //  CREATE PROCEDURE IdentityProcedure 
        //  AS
        //  BEGIN
        //      INSERT Customers
        //      VALUES
        //      ('TEST','TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', 'TEST', GETDATE())
        //      RETURN @@IDENTITY -- процедура возвращает значение автоинкремента добавленной строки
        //  END
        //  GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExecuteNonQuery используется для того, что написано в его имени - исполнения процедуры без возврата результата запроса.

Дело в том, что хранимая процедура в TSQL может возвращать значения двумя путями: через результирующие наборы (когда в процедуре есть предложения SELECT без INSERT INTO) и через возвращаемое значение (предложение RETURN). В случае первого способа данные можно получить через ExecuteReader или ExecuteScalar, а во втором случае необходимо использовать ExecuteNonQuery и считать возвращаемое значение через параметр ReturnValue, как это сделано в коде из вопроса.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, мне не совсем понятно как технически это происходит. Если cmd не возвращает параметру значение через процедуру, то как оно оказывается в parameter.value которое вызвано на объекте cmd?

Comment: @Konih Эта логика зашита в ADO.NET, точнее в провайдере для SQL Server. ExecuteNonQuery, хоть и не возвращает значение, заполняет все выходные параметры, а ReturnValue является особым типом выходного параметра.

Comment: @Konih - Если вас интересует, как именно реализована передача данных _внутри_, то могу посоветовать книгу Mastering SQL, Martin Gruber, в русском переводе: SQL, Мартин Грабер. См. раздел Using Descriptor Areas / Использование областей дескриптора.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно рассмотрю данную книгу. Объясните, пожалуйста, Return.Value получает значение как результат работы процедуры IdentityProcedure или ф-ии  InsertCustomer() ? И что раньше происходит возвращается значение из процедуры/ф-ии в переменную int customerNo = InsertCustomer(); или записывается в Return.Value?

Comment: @Konih Значение параметра ReturnValue записывается **ExecuteNonQuery**, на основе того, что передано в предложение RETURN в процедуре IdentityProcedure. Конечно, это происходит раньше возврата из InsertCustomer - как могло бы быть иначе?

Comment: Ясно, Тогда получается в переменную customerNo ф-ей InsertCustomer будет передано значение из Return.Value, а не из процедуры непосредственно?

Comment: @Konih Да, это так. Непосредственно вы не можете вернуть возвращаемое значение хранимой процедуры, так как она выполняется в другой программе, поэтому для получения этого значения необходим этот специальный функционал ADO.NET

Comment: Cпасибо за подробный ответ